# 1 to 1 inverse relationship "belongsTo" giving a collection laravel instead of model

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

In my **Profile** model I setted this relationship

```
    public function lease()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Lease::class, 'lease_id', 'id');
}
```

And in my **Lease** model I seeted this way

```
public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Profile::class, 'lease_id', id);
}
```

As longs as I know in laravel you could do

```
$profile = factory(App\Profile::class)->create();
```

`$profile->lease()->get();`

And then responds correctly with the model inside of a collection
And if I do 
`$profile->lease`
Responds correctly directly with the model

It isn't supposed that dynamic propertis execute the query right away like a shortcut of ->lease()->get()? Why it gives different formatted results?

Comment: 1 profile can have multiple leases, 1 lease has 1 profile

Comment: I forgot to say that it should be a one-to-one relationship. As I see in the documentation **We can define the inverse of a hasOne relationship using the belongsTo method**
Is there other way?

Comment: technically it is still possible to have multiple leases for the same profile, if you want 1 to 1 - you have to declare these fields in the same table

Comment: So you say that I should put a 'leases.profile_id' and declare it also as a hasOne instead of a belongsTo?

Comment: no, you need to define only 1 model

Comment: Which table is the foreign key on? it looks to me like your relations are around the wrong way, assuming a Lease has the foreign key.

Comment: I have **lease_id** in **profiles**, and nothing to relate in leases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are calling `get` on a builder you are getting a collection always. When you call `first` on a builder like that you will get a model or null. The dynamic property for the relationship, based upon the relationship object, will either query with `get` or `first` respectively when it loads it. Which is why `$model->relationship` is returning you the result you expect.

The relationships that are singular, cause a `find` and the ones that are many cause a `get`.

[Laravel 5.4 - Docs - Eloquent - Relations - Relationship Methods vs Dynamic Properties](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#relationship-methods-vs-dynamic-properties)

Comment: wow **The relationships that are singular, cause a find and the ones that are many cause a get.** is there a way to specify manually when to apply get() or first() in a dynamic property

Comment: @JosePalazuelos no ... its based on the relationship type... a hasOne would never return many. a hasMany is expected to return many. You have to decide what you want your relationship to be :)